# How to Resize the Swf inside Swf?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, resize

> Hai i tried to load a swf(text.swf) inside swf(video.swf).In my (text.swf)i passed some text.while i resize the (text.swf),the text inside the (text.swf) is Changed.Without Changing the Content how can i resize the (text.swf)?Actually my Size of text.swf is 400*44px.If i run alone text.swf size is small,But when i added to (video.swf)the size of text.chat very large.So only i resize the text.swf,But content inside the ?(text.swf)also changed.How can i solve this problem?Anybody help me

Thanks in advance
here my coding

```
     _loader.load(new URLRequest("text.swf"));
     _loader.x=(((_stage.stageHeight)/100)*0.1);
     _loader.y=(((_stage.stageWidth)/100)*49);
     _loader.height=((_stage.stageWidth)/25);
     _loader.width=(((_stage.stageWidth)));

     mainContainer.addChild(_loader);
```

Comment: Why this -1,If u put -1 For my Question Atleast give the Explanation What's the Reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time try to format your question text a bit (add some newlines, use a space after .,? and check how it looks in the preview before submitting).

Maybe the following code might help you:

```
/**
 * Reset text to original scale
 */
function resetTextScaling(aContainer: DisplayObjectContainer): void
{
  for(var index: int = aContainer.numChildren; index--; )
  {
    var child: DisplayObject = aContainer.getChildAt(index);
    if (child is TextField)
    {
      var parentMatrix: Matrix = child.parent.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
      // calc area of child as visible
      var childWidth: Number = child.width * parentMatrix.a / child.scaleX;
      var childHeight: Number = child.height * parentMatrix.d / child.scaleY;
      // restore original font size
      child.scaleX /= parentMatrix.a;
      child.scaleY /= parentMatrix.d;
      // resize child so it still uses the same area 
      child.width = childWidth;
      child.height = childHeight;
    }
    else if (child is DisplayObjectContainer)
    {
      // process children
      resetTextScaling(child as DisplayObjectContainer);
    }
  }
}

// make this call after _loader has been added to the stage 
// and has completed loading
resetTextScaling(_loader);
```